# Laravel Slack documentation?

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, slack-api, slack

I've read the page about the new notifications in Laravel 5.3, and seen some tutorials from Laracasts, but I would like to know what is available in terms of variables etc.

In the Slack API documentation, I can see that I can create buttons in the notification, however, the notification (using SlackMessage) shows that I can't use action() and it throws

**Error**

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SlackMessage::action()

Does anyone have some information about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is you are reading the documentation wrongly. According to  [Laravel's Slack Notification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#slack-notifications), it doesn't help you create "button" in Slack.

The [Laravel Notification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#introduction) is a mechanism for you to create notification through different channels, like SMS (Nexmo), Database, Emails, Slack. So if you think about this carefully, "button" is actually not a common pattern in these channels, hence `action` is not implemented here in Slack.

In contract, the `action` method found in `SimpleMessage` or `MailMessage` is actually referring to "call-to-**action**" button. It helps you create a button in the email nicely. This is not true in other type of notifications, such as `DatabaseMessage`, `NexmoMessage`, or `SlackMessage`. You simply don't (or doesn't make sense) to create buttons in these channels.

If you need to create additional content with `SlackMessage`, simply extend it and build one for your own.

Comment: Basically, what I want is to be able to do this: https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons

Why wouldn't this make sense to create?

Comment: This is too specific for Laravel I think, hence it's not implemented. I would suggest you to create one for yourself by extending the `SlackMessage` class.